# How to create a new view model to pass to a detail view from a list without breaking MVVM?

Tags: swiftui, mvvm

I'm looking for some help or clarification on whether my current understanding of SwiftUI breaks MVVM or not. This is part of a code challenge for a job I desperately need so really appreciate any comments.

My main view pulls in models from my view model `characterManager` to populate a list. Each item in the list contains a `NavigationLink` to navigate to a detail view. I need to pass the model to the detail view and build a view model for the detail view to use but I'm not sure where this view model should be created. Currently I'm creating the new `CharacterDetailViewModel` in the `CharacterListView` and passing to the detail view's `init` function. I'm not sure if it is right to create a view model directly in the view.

Here's my main view where the list is populated using `character` models and passed into a detail view with a new `CharacterDetailViewModel`:

```
struct CharacterListView: View {
    @StateObject var characterManager = CharacterManager()
    @StateObject var realmManager = RealmManager()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            if characterManager.isLoading {
                ProgressView()
            } else {
                List(characterManager.characters) { character in
                    NavigationLink {
                        CharacterDetailView(characterViewModel: CharacterDetailViewModel(character: character))
                    } label: {
                        Text(character.name)
                    }
                }
                .navigationTitle("Characters")
            }
        }
        .environmentObject(characterManager)
        .environmentObject(realmManager)
    }
}
```

And this is the detail view where the view model is set in the `init`

```
struct CharacterDetailView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var characterManager: CharacterManager
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: CharacterDetailViewModel
  
    init(characterViewModel: CharacterDetailViewModel) {
        self.viewModel = characterViewModel
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ...
    }
}
```

Is this a legal way to do what I'm trying to achieve or is there a better way to do this? The company I'm applying to uses MVVM with SwiftUI so I have to stick with this architecture.

Answer (score 0):

I would make it simple and directly use the Character model into the application without the use if a view model. In SwiftUI, view is the View Model so in most cases you don't need to create separate VM for each screen. I would use the following approach.

```
@MainActor
class CharacterManager: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var characters: [Character] = []
    
    func fetchCharacters() {
        characters = [Character(name: "Character 1"), Character(name: "Character 2")]
    }
}

struct Character: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let name: String
}

struct CharacterDetailView: View {
    
    let character: Character
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(character.name)
            .font(.largeTitle)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @StateObject private var characterManager = CharacterManager()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List(characterManager.characters) { character in
                NavigationLink {
                    CharacterDetailView(character: character)
                } label: {
                    Text(character.name)
                }
            }.onAppear {
                characterManager.fetchCharacters()
            }
        }
    }
}
```